# Where and how can I earn Heart Scales?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

If you don't know this is cost for one usage of Move Relearner (in Dendemille Town) skills.

Comment: I heard the best way to get those, is by stealing them from [Luvdiscs](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Luvdisc). Each one has a 50% chance of holding a Heart Scale. Unfortunately, I don't know where you can encounter Luvdiscs in X or Y.

Comment: @Nolonar - I must catch them or win with them? Where they are and with which rod I can interact with them ?

Comment: You can catch them, or you can use the [Thief move](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Thief_%28move%29) instead so you don't need to catch or defeat the Pokémon. Like I said before, I don't know where or how to find a Luvdisc in X or Y, sorry.

Answer (score 10):

Fish with the **old rod** at Route 8, 12, Ambrette Town, Azure Bay, Cyllage City in Pokemon X or Y. You can steal them from Luvdisc with a 50% chance of them being held.

Or you can get one daily from Tierno in Couramine City after beating the Elite Four,        if you have a Pokemon knowing the move he wants to see.

I had stolen about 10 heart scales in a matter of minutes.

Edit: If you want to kill 2 birds with one stone, use a Pokemon with the move called "[Covet](http://pokemondb.net/move/covet)". Not only will it steal the item, but it will damage the target pokemon in hopes of fainting it to gain experience.

Comment: Note that Thief works even if it knocks out the Luvdisc, so it's most efficient to use a Pokemon that can one-hit KO.

Comment: @dlras2 Thieft works good too, I prefer covet because of the higher attack power and PP.

Comment: Make sure the pokemon using Thief doesn't already have an item.

Comment: Illumise works great for farming indefinitely, with it's ability to learn both Thief (via TM) and Covet (level 45), as well as Moonlight for HP recovery. All you need is a PP O-power every now and then and you'll never have to leave. (Of course, Smeargle can also do this :P)

Comment: If you use a Malamar with Suction Cups and have him know Thief, you can farm for Heart Scales and chain fish at the same time, potentialy getting some Shiny Luvdiscs while getting Heart Scales.

Answer (score 3):

Using a Pokemon with the ability Frisk is the best thing to do.My Trevenant allows me to easily find Heart Scales.

Comment: That is a good point.

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten lots of Heart Scales just from using Rock Smash on breakable boulders.  My favorite place to go is the beach outside Ambrette Town (Route 8, Muraille Coast) because you can break the 2 rocks in the main area (with the tree growing in the middle of the sand for some reason) and then head around to the left down the coastline where there are more rocks to break and then when you backtrack to the other area, the rocks reset and you can just keep going back and forth.  This is also a good way of getting really valuable items that can be sold for high prices such as Star Pieces (which sell for almost $5000 each), Stardust, pearls, etc.  Also, I've gotten Hard Stones and Soft Sands (which are held items you can give to your rock- and ground-type pokemon, respectively, that boost those types of moves).  To me, this seems more rewarding than repeatedly trying to catch a Luvdisc and steal its held item because only about half of them are actually carrying Heart Scales and you still have other wild pokemon that are no doubt going to be getting in your way as well.

Some things to keep in mind, though, are that you will occasionally still encounter wild pokemon (Dwebble or Binacle) or not get anything at all.  The wild pokemon under these rocks are only like level 20, so if you have a higher level pokemon in your first slot, you can just run away or OHKO it to earn some extra EXP. I like to put in a movie to watch and then get on my DS and just break rocks for a few hours to let stuff build up, then go sell it all when the movie's over.  If you equip your bike it's even faster to get from one rock to the next (obviously).  Also, this way you're racking up PokeMiles, too.  Anyway, good luck.  =D

Comment: Remember, you can also find fossils this way!

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but using thief/covet/frisk doesn't require catching which is pretty awesome. Your idea is great if you want to multitask though!

Comment: "and you still have other wild pokemon that are no doubt going to be getting in your way as well" - this is not true. Every single location with Old Rod Luvdiscs has 100% encounter rate in Pokémon X and Pokémon Y.

Answer (score 0):

One other way to obtain large quantities of Heart scales rather quickly is to use the Game Sync feature to connect your game to an account at [Pokemon Global Link](http://www.pokemon-gl.com/) If you do a lot of trading by the GTS or Wonder Trade, you can accumulate a rather large quantity of pokemiles. At the Global Link website, these pokemiles can be turned in for various rewards. Although (currently) the only ones worth their cost seem to be Heart Scales (100 each), Rare Candies (250 each) and PP up (500 each).

Note that while heat scales can also be obtained with pokemiles from an NPC in the Lumiose South Boulevard Pokecenter, his prices are double those found on the website. So unless the website is not a viable option for you, Buying from the NPC isn't worth the extra cost.

Comment: Note that PokeMiles are [generated via Streetpasses](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134250/what-effects-does-streetpass-have-with-pokemon-x-y) as well

Comment: @Robotnik ehhh, yeah - but unless you're traveling, or 'fake' the location on a second 3ds, each local streetpass tag seems to net exactly 1 pokemile each. It might be useful for some people, but it's hardly what I'd call efficient or quick for most day-to-day pokemile earning.

Comment: Ah OK, I get about 20 passes a day through commuting, so I suppose its only beneficial for those in densely populated areas

Answer (score 0):

There is one on the path beside the pokemom center at Ambrette Town

Answer (score 0):

I have found the perfect Pokemon for the job. Grab a [Noivern](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/715.shtml) with the ability Frisk (one of its natural ability, and easy to spot), teach him Thief, and then go fishing for wild Luvdiscs. If one is holding an item of interest, just thief. If not, then KO it or run away. Remember to take the item from Noivern before repeating!